# Difference between set and select in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between `set` and `select` in SQL Server as both the keywords are used to assign a parameter value in Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

`SET` uses to assign single value whereas `SELECT` uses to assign multiple values. For example

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE (ProductId INT,ProductCode VARCHAR(10), Name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Product(ProductId,ProductCode,Name) 
(SELECT 1,'P001','Computer')

DECLARE @variable1 INT,@variable2 AS VARCHAR(100),@variable3 AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @variable1 = (SELECT ProductId FROM @Product)

SELECT @variable2 =  ProductCode, @variable3 = Name FROM @Product
SELECT @variable1,@variable2,@variable3
```